# If $g\in C^1(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$ and $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ is bounded, is $g(u)$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded function. Assume that $g\in C^1(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$. It is possible to conclude that $g(u)$ is bounded itself?

If yes, does it come from that it is composition of a continuous and bounded functions?

Comment: I am curious about the source of this problem. A similar question appeared  a few minutes ago (by a different user)  and it was deleted.

Comment: In my case, it is the final step of an exercise for my physic class and I just wanted to be sure that I was arguing right. Many classmates post questions here (I can not guarantee it was any of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $u$ is bounded, $u(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in some compact set $K$. As $g$ is continuous, $g(K)$ is also compact, and consequently a bounded set. As

$$(g\circ u)(\mathbb{R})\subseteq g(K)$$

it follows that $(g\circ u)(\mathbb{R})$ is a bounded set, and consequently $g\circ u$ is bounded.